# Is it possible to nest one VML roundrect within another?

Tags: nested, vml

For example:

```
<v:roundrect style="display:block;width:100px;height:100px;" fillcolor="#eee">
Hi
    <v:roundrect style="display:block;width:50px;height:50px;" fillcolor="#c00">
        Hey
    </v:roundrect>
</v:roundrect>
```

I can't see the background of the inner roundrect when I use this markup.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is an interesting article that touches on some of this, ultimately settling on an unusual but workable way of using vml shape paths: https://kontent.ai/blog/emails-outlook-containers-rounded-courners

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No VML shapes can be nested inside each other.  You need to position them so they overlap correctly.

```
<div style="position:relative;">
  <v:roundrect style="display:block;width:100px;height:100px;" fillcolor="#eee">
    Hi 
  </v:roundrect> 
  <v:roundrect style="display:block;width:50px;height:50px; top: 25px; left:25px;  position:absolute;" fillcolor="#c00"> 
    Hey 
  </v:roundrect>
</div>
```

Comment: That's a pity, I wanted to wrap them around divs, but the divs might be nested within one another. Anyway, thanks for the reply.

Comment: Source please ?